# Accessing member of class through shared pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I am facing a issue, when I try to access members of a class through a shared pointer.

The program runs fine and gives the expected output: `"Name: Michel"`. But when I comment the line marked as `COMMENT_THIS_LINE`, it gives some junk value instead of `Michel`. Can anybody explain this behavior, and how I can get the correct output without the marked line?

```
class TestShared{
public:
    TestShared(std::string name);
    std::string getName(void);
private:
    std::string m_name;
};

class Another{
public:
    const char *name;
};

TestShared::TestShared(std::string name) : m_name(name)
{
}

std::string TestShared::getName(void)
{
    return m_name;
}

std::shared_ptr<TestShared> allocate_ts()
{
    char p[] = "Michel";
    return std::make_shared<TestShared>(p);
}

Another GetAnother(std::shared_ptr<TestShared>  ts)
{
    Another an;
    std::string a = ts->getName();    //////////COMMENT_THIS_LINE
    an.name = ts->getName().c_str();
    return an;
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<TestShared>  ts = allocate_ts();
    Another an = GetAnother(ts);
    printf("Name: %s\n", an.name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that in C++ a function with no arguments has the type `ReturnType function()`. Saying `ReturnType function(void)` is C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important bits are this:

```
std::string TestShared::getName(void)
{
    return m_name;
}
```

And this:

```
Another an;
an.name = ts->getName().c_str();   // (*)
return an;
```

`getName()` returns a copy of the private string. `c_str()` returns a pointer to that temporary's internal character array. `an.name` stores that pointer, which is dangling already at the `;` in `(*)`.

You need to copy the string, or simply don't use a `char*` pointer when you actually want a `string`.

Returning a reference to the member `m_name` from `getName()` would fix the immediate issue as well, but if you want `an.name` to store a string you should actually store a string, not just the pointer to some other string's internal buffer.

Your code has undefined behavior, because at the time you print the string via `printf("Name: %s\n", an.name);` the pointer is not valid anymore. The `string` it was pointing to is long gone. Undefined behavior can have weird effects, for example adding a seemingly unrelated line changing the behavior. Don't get misled by your code producing expected output when the extra line of code is present. This is just a side effect, your code is wrong, even if it appears to work.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but how ts->getName().c_str() becomes dangling. the address is still valid. How commenting and uncommenting the line changes the address status?

Comment: @coolgoose No, `getName()` returns a temporary against which you call `c_str()`.  When the temporary goes out of scope and is destroyed so is the memory pointed to by the value returned by `c_str()`.

Comment: @coolgoose The fact that the program sometimes appears to work doesn't imply that it is actually correct at those times. Your program exhibits undefined behaviour for the reasons pointed out in this post.

Comment: @coolgoose no the adress is not valid anymore. it is similar to `std::string * x = &(ts->getName());` just that this won't compile. Unfortunately you did manage to get a pointer to a temporary object (via `c_str`). There is nothing you can do with that pointer without undefined behavior.